# Как ассемблер транслирует мнемокод в машинный код?

Tags: ассемблер, машинный-код

Хочется понять, как ассемблер транслирует по сути текст в машинный код? И что из себя представляет машинный код? И что тогда идёт после машинного кода?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "текстом"? Как процессор понимает слово "Привет"?

Comment: https://www.heavy.ai/technical-glossary/llvm

Comment: Кстати, в профильных вузах есть целая дисциплина - системное программирование, в рамках которой, в частности, преподаётся разработка ассемблера. Более того, студенты обязаны в качестве курсового проекта написать свой простенький ассемблер. Помню, как я написал такой урезанный для x86, потом написал программу "hello world" под ms dos, скомпилировал своим недоассемблером и запустил - непередаваемое чувство!))) А препод ещё не хотел принимать мою работу. Так что добро пожаловать в ВУЗ;))

Comment: Каждая инструкция ISA CPU имеет свой определенный формат в машинных кодах (т.е. представляется определенными набором байтов). За каждой инструкций также закреплена определенная мнемоника на языке ассемблера (есть правда инструкции для которых не определена мнемоника). В ассемблер, грубо говоря, вшита таблица соответствий между мнемониками и форматом байт машинного кода. И ассемблер переводит каждую мнемонику в машинный код в соответствии с этой вшитой информацией. После машинного кода потенциально может идти микрокод.

Comment: @eanmos А что из себя представляет микрокод? Что это по сути своей?

Comment: @evan, микрокод исполняет машинный код, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode, там тоже свой ассемблер

Comment: насчёт ассемблера и машинного кода, берите описание любого интересного вам процессора и смотрите раздел `Instruction set`